# Hardware that receives 2 touch monitors input at once and gives it to windows as one?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

We have two multitouch monitors connected to the same windows PC.  When both monitors are touched at the same time, only one monitor receives the touch input.  We need some kind of box that can receive both touch inputs from the monitors and pass it along to windows as one.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be very appreciated.